# Can I observe what is added HTML from the rendering begins?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I want to detect all changes to html document from the time the web request has been requested to its response fully rendered. I am using MutationObserver. Simply as the below. But it only catches the mutations to children of 'head' and 'body' nodes. I want it upper level in the DOM tree, so to catch the 'head' node has been added to html document. I call this script below from my background script when the first batch of 'chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived' delivered from the website. I am not sure if I am doing this very late or it is not possible to catch them.

```
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

        for (const m of mutations) {
                for (const n of m.addedNodes) {
                    console.log('mutation:', n);
                }   
        }


});

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true
});
```

Comment: Can you do an AJAX call to retrieve the entire webpage before you run MutationObserver?

Comment: Yes it's possible,..?